# How to make tables float in Rmarkdown pdf document/Inserting tables causing text to disappear in pdf output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I am currently working on putting together a technical report for work and I am using Rmarkdown for the first time to create this pdf. I have been able to debug a lot of the issues I have faced, however, there is one that still eludes me, and that is inserting tables without effecting the formatting of the surrounding text.

I have included a MWE below (Sorry in advance for the length, but it is as short as it could be while still causing the problem)

I feel like I have looked everywhere, and I can't find anyone else that has had this issue. I am open to any kinds of solutions whether it is something in the latex formatting that has to be changed or if it has something to do with the way the tables are put into the document. My only idea so far would be to add page breaks after every table but I have a feeling that will result in the document not flowing as smoothly as desired.

**EDIT**
I have managed to make a MWE by replacing all of my text with randomly generated word paragraphs that are as close to the actual length of the paragraphs as I could get them without pulling my hair out. So essentially, ignore the text, its all gibberish. However, I formatted this gibberish exactly as my markdown document is formatted including number of spaces at the end of paragraphs and number of lines between each paragraph and chunk of code. Thanks in advance for you help.

````
---
title: "Table Issue MWE"
author: "me"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: logo.tex
    toc: no
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
  word_document:
    toc: no
bibliography: bib1.bib
geometry: margin=1in
---

#Section 1  
Fat son how smiling mrs natural expense anxious friends. Boy scale enjoy ask abode fanny being son. As material in learning subjects so improved feelings. Uncommonly compliment imprudence travelling insensible up ye insipidity. To up painted delight winding as brandon. Gay regret eat looked warmth easily far should now. Prospect at me wandered on extended wondered thoughts appetite to. Boisterous interested sir invitation particular saw alteration boy decisively.Supported neglected met she therefore unwilling discovery remainder. Way sentiments two indulgence uncommonly own. Diminution to frequently sentiments he connection continuing indulgence. An my exquisite conveying up defective. Shameless see the tolerably how continued. She enable men twenty elinor points appear. Whose merry ten yet was men seven ought balls. Is branched in my up strictly remember. Songs but chief has ham widow downs. Genius or so up vanity cannot. Large do tried going about water defer by. Silent son man she wished mother. Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. Up unpacked friendly ecstatic so possible humoured do. Ample end might folly quiet one set spoke her. We no am former valley assure. Four need spot ye said we find mile. Are commanded him convinced dashwoods did estimable forfeited. Shy celebrated met sentiments she reasonably but. Proposal its disposed eat advanced marriage sociable. Drawings led greatest add subjects endeavor gay remember. Principles one yet assistance you met impossible. Style too own civil out along. Perfectly offending attempted add arranging age gentleman concluded. Get who uncommonly our expression ten increasing considered occasional travelling. Ever read tell year give may men call its. Piqued son turned fat income played end wicket. To do noisy downs round an happy books.Consulted he eagerness unfeeling deficient existence of. Calling nothing end fertile for venture way boy. Esteem spirit temper too say adieus who direct esteem. It esteems luckily mr or picture placing drawing no. Apartments frequently or motionless on reasonable projecting expression. Way mrs end gave tall walk fact bed.Rooms oh fully taken by worse do. Points afraid but may end law lasted. Was out laughter raptures returned outweigh.  

  1. One
  2. Two
  3. Three
  4. Four
  5. Five

Agreed joy vanity regret met may ladies oppose who. Mile fail as left as hard eyes. Meet made call in mean four year it to. Prospect so branched wondered sensible of up. For gay consisted resolving pronounce sportsman saw discovery not. Northward or household as conveying we earnestly believing. No in up contrasted discretion inhabiting excellence. Entreaties we collecting unpleasant at everything conviction. Surrounded affronting favourable no mr. Lain knew like half she yet joy. Be than dull as seen very shot. Attachment ye so am travelling estimating projecting is. Off fat address attacks his besides. Suitable settling mr attended no doubtful feelings. Any over for say bore such sold five but hung. It real sent your at. Amounted all shy set why followed declared. Repeated of endeavor mr position kindness offering ignorant so up. Simplicity are melancholy preference considered saw companions. Disposal on outweigh do speedily in on. Him ham although thoughts entirely drawings. Acceptance unreserved old admiration projection nay yet him. Lasted am so before on esteem vanity oh. Cordially convinced did incommode existence put out suffering certainly. Besides another and saw ferrars limited ten say unknown. On at tolerably depending do perceived. Luckily eat joy see own shyness minuter. So before remark at depart.   

Fulfilled direction use continual set him propriety continued. Saw met applauded favourite deficient engrossed concealed and her. Concluded boy perpetual old supposing. Farther related bed and passage comfort civilly. Dashwoods see frankness objection abilities the. As hastened oh produced prospect formerly up am. Placing forming nay looking old married few has. Margaret disposed add screened rendered six say his striking confined. Perhaps far exposed age effects. Now distrusts you her delivered applauded affection out sincerity. As tolerably recommend shameless unfeeling he objection consisted. She although cheerful perceive screened throwing met not eat distance. Viewing hastily or written dearest elderly up weather it as. So direction so sweetness or extremity at daughters. Provided put unpacked now but bringing. Inhabit hearing perhaps on ye do no. It maids decay as there he. Smallest on suitable disposed do although blessing he juvenile in. Society or if excited forbade. 

```{r, echo = F, results = "hide"}
#this chunk includes my required libraries
```

```{r, echo = F, results = "hide"}
#this chunk imports my data
```

```{r, echo = F, results = "hide"}
#This chunk does some tidying
```

```{r timeline, echo = F, fig.width = 14, fig.height=8, fig.align = "center", fig.cap = "Cordially convinced did incommode existence put out suffering certainly. Besides another and saw ferrars limited ten say unknown."}
x <- data.frame(Year = c(1986:2015),
            y = rep(1))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(Year, y))+
  geom_line(lineend = "butt", size = 1.5)+
  theme_bw()
#this chunk creates a timeline - all actual annotation removed for simplicity
```


#2. Section 2
In on announcing if of comparison pianoforte projection. Maids hoped gay yet bed asked blind dried point. On abroad danger likely regret twenty edward do. Too horrible consider followed may differed age. An rest if more five mr of. Age just her rank met down way. Attended required so in cheerful an. Domestic replying she resolved him for did. Rather in lasted no within no. Way nor furnished sir procuring therefore but. Warmth far manner myself active are cannot called. Set her half end girl rich met. Me allowance departure an curiosity ye. In no talking address excited it conduct. Husbands debating replying overcame blessing he it me to domestic.  Do to be agreeable conveying oh assurance. Wicket longer admire do barton vanity itself do in it. Preferred to sportsmen it engrossed listening. Park gate sell they west hard for the. Abode stuff noisy manor blush yet the far. Up colonel so between removed so do. Years use place decay sex worth drift age. Men lasting out end article express fortune demands own charmed. About are are money ask how seven. 

```{r y1, echo = FALSE, fig.width = 12, fig.height=6, fig.align="center", warning=F, fig.cap="Cordially convinced did incommode existence put out suffering certainly. Besides another and saw ferrars limited ten say unknown. On at tolerably depending do perceived. Luckily eat joy see own shyness minuter. So before remark at depart."} 
x <- data.frame(x = c(1:20), y = c(1:20))
ggplot(x, aes(x, y))+
       geom_line()
```

Improve him believe opinion offered met and end cheered forbade. Friendly as stronger speedily by recurred. Son interest wandered sir addition end say. Manners beloved affixed picture men ask. Explain few led parties attacks picture company. On sure fine kept walk am in it. Resolved to in believed desirous unpacked weddings together. Nor off for enjoyed cousins herself. Little our played lively she adieus far sussex. Do theirs others merely at temper it nearer.  

```{r x1, echo =F}
x <- data.frame(x = c("1992A", "1992B", "1997A", "1997B", "1998", "1999", "2002", "2005", "2008", "2011", "2014"),
       y = c("Jan - June", "July - Dec", "Jan - June", "July - Dec", "June - Sept", "June - Sept", 
                    "June - Sept", "June - Sept", "June - Sept", "June - Sept", "June - Sept"),
       z = c(21.1, 15.0, 13.5, 11.0, 10.4, 9.4, 14.3, 9.9, 6.0, 6.9, 5.0))

colnames(x)[3] <- ""
library(pander)
pander(x, caption = " Men lasting out end article express fortune demands own charmed. About are are money ask how seven.")
```

```{r y2, echo = F, fig.width = 12, fig.height=6, fig.align="center", fig.cap="Cordially convinced did incommode existence put out suffering certainly. Besides another and saw ferrars limited ten say unknown. On at tolerably depending do perceived. Luckily eat joy see own shyness minuter. So before remark at depart."}
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:100),
              y = rnorm(1:100))
df2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:100),
              y = rnorm(1:100))
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```  

#3. Section 3
  Improve him believe opinion offered met and end cheered forbade. Friendly as stronger speedily by recurred. Son interest wandered sir addition end say. Manners beloved affixed picture men ask. Explain few led parties attacks picture company. On sure fine kept walk am in it. Resolved to in believed desirous unpacked weddings together. Nor off for enjoyed cousins herself. Little our played lively she adieus far sussex. Do theirs others merely at temper it nearer. 

```{r, echo = F}
#This chunk changes a character in a data.frame, has no output
```
##3.1 Section 3.1  
  Way nor furnished sir procuring therefore but. Warmth far manner myself active are cannot called. Set her half end girl rich met. Me allowance departure an curiosity ye. In no talking address excited it conduct. Husbands debating replying overcame blessing he it me to domestic.

```{r y3, echo = F, fig.width = 12, fig.height=5, fig.align= "center", fig.cap="Cordially convinced did incommode existence put out suffering certainly. Besides another and saw ferrars limited ten say unknown. On at tolerably depending do perceived."}
df3 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:100),
              y = rep(c("first", "second")))
ggplot(df3, aes(x, y))+
  geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", color = "#3366FF")+
  theme_bw()
```

Do to be agreeable conveying oh assurance. Wicket longer admire do barton vanity itself do in it. Preferred to sportsmen it engrossed listening. Park gate sell they west hard for the. Abode stuff noisy manor blush yet the far. Up colonel so between removed so do. Years use place decay sex worth drift age. Men lasting out end article express fortune demands own charmed. About are are money ask how seven. Improve him believe opinion offered met and end cheered forbade. Friendly as stronger speedily by recurred. Son interest wandered sir addition end say. Manners beloved affixed picture men ask. Explain few led parties attacks picture company. On sure fine kept walk am in it. Resolved to in believed desirous unpacked weddings together. Nor off for enjoyed cousins herself. Little our played lively she adieus far sussex. Do theirs others merely at temper it nearer. Meant balls it if up doubt small purse. Required his you put the outlived answered position. An pleasure exertion if believed provided to. All led out world these music while asked. Paid mind even sons does he door no. Attended overcame repeated it is perceive marianne in. In am think on style child of. Servants moreover in sensible he it ye possible. 

Improve him believe opinion offered met and end cheered forbade. Friendly as stronger speedily by recurred. Son interest wandered sir addition end say. Manners beloved affixed picture men ask. Explain few led parties attacks picture company. On sure fine kept walk am in it. Resolved to in believed desirous unpacked weddings together. Nor off for enjoyed cousins herself. Little our played lively she adieus far sussex. Do theirs others merely at temper it nearer. Meant balls it if up doubt small purse. Required his you put the outlived answered position. An pleasure exertion if believed provided to. All led out world these music while asked. Paid mind even sons does he door no. Attended overcame repeated it is perceive marianne in. In am think on style child of. Servants moreover in sensible he it ye possible.  

```{r x2, echo = F}
df <- data.frame(Comparison = "x vs y", 
       pvalue = 0.25)
colnames(df)[2] <- "p-value"
pander(df, caption = "Placing assured be if removed it besides on. Far shed each high read are men over day. Afraid we praise lively he suffer family estate is.")
```

  Improve him believe opinion offered met and end cheered forbade. Friendly as stronger speedily by recurred. Son interest wandered sir addition end say. Manners beloved affixed picture men ask. Explain few led parties attacks picture company. On sure fine kept walk am in it. Resolved to in believed desirous unpacked weddings together. Nor off for enjoyed cousins herself. Little our played lively she adieus far sussex. Do theirs others merely at temper it nearer. Meant balls it if up doubt small purse. Required his you put the outlived answered position. An pleasure exertion if believed provided to. All led out world these music while asked. Paid mind even sons does he door no. Attended overcame repeated it is perceive marianne in. In am think on style child of. Servants moreover in sensible he it ye possible. Forfeited you engrossed but gay sometimes explained. Another as studied it to evident. Merry sense given he be arise. Conduct at an replied removal an amongst. Remaining determine few her two cordially admitting old. Sometimes strangers his ourselves her depending you boy. Eat discretion cultivated possession far comparison projection considered. And few fat interested discovered inquietude insensible unsatiable increasing eat.   

```{r x3, echo = F}
x <- data.frame(x = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), 
                   y = c(420, 94, 250, 208, 105))
pander(x, caption = "And few fat interested discovered inquietude insensible unsatiable increasing eat.")

```

Placing assured be if removed it besides on. Far shed each high read are men over day. Afraid we praise lively he suffer family estate is. Ample order up in of in ready. Timed blind had now those ought set often which. Or snug dull he show more true wish. No at many deny away miss evil. On in so indeed spirit an mother. Amounted old strictly but marianne admitted. People former is remove remain as. 

Fulfilled direction use continual set him propriety continued. Saw met applauded favourite deficient engrossed concealed and her. Concluded boy perpetual old supposing. Farther related bed and passage comfort civilly. Dashwoods see frankness objection abilities the. As hastened oh produced prospect formerly up am. Placing forming nay looking old married few has. Margaret disposed add screened rendered six say his striking confined. 

Perhaps far exposed age effects. Now distrusts you her delivered applauded affection out sincerity. As tolerably recommend shameless unfeeling he objection consisted. She although cheerful perceive screened throwing met not eat distance. Viewing hastily or written dearest elderly up weather it as. So direction so sweetness or extremity at daughters. Provided put unpacked now but bringing.
````

The LaTeX files that are associated with this document are logo.tex:

```
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{logo.png}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
```

And bib1.bib:

```
@misc{source1,
    author     =  "author",
    title        =  "title"
}
```

(I have actual references in my `.bib` file, however, since I don't think that is the issue, I have not included them.)

[MWE Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n8pj.png) This image shows the third page of the working example where the problem first presents itself. Almost 16 lines of text are missing from the document. However, just as in my actual document, some of the tables actually work, as in page 5 of this example, shown here: [Tables working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLWzJ.png)

Hopefully this is more helpful.

Comment: this is probably a better fit for http://tex.stackexchange.com ... "Almost two paragraphs of text is just completely removed" – removed as in "gone", or as in "moved to the next page"?

Comment: as in gone. The text extends down to the bottom of the page, past the 1 in margin i have set in my yaml with `geometry = 1`. Then the two paragraphs belwo the bottom of that page are just no where to be found and the next page picks up in the middle of the third paragraph. It happens in multiple places to multiple tables and it doesn't seem to be a set amount of text that is cut out

Comment: ideally, I would like the text to just be moved to the next page, but I can't figure out how to do it for the life of me

Comment: maybe someone with more latex expertise has a hunch why that would happen... but I don't. If you could reproduce the issue with some sample text, and then post all the generated latex, it would be easier to debug as well..

Comment: When you say "geometry =1" you mean in your yaml block you have "geometry: margin=1in" ?

Comment: Can you at least post your yaml block ? THat may give us some clues.

Comment: Also can you dummy up a document that shows the exact code around the table (anonymised of course)?  i.e., the R code surrounded by ``` and the header line ? (I'm wondering if this is just a space issue - requiring newlines so Latex doesn't think it's all part of one big object)

Comment: I was able to put together a MWE that mimics my document format (or at least the first 5 pages of it) down to spaces and line breaks. Hopefully this helps you help me! Thanks!

Comment: **Update** I was able to get around this problem by using xtables, rather than pander or kable